# RunAs as a different user

Tags: windows, elevated-privileges, runas

If I from an elevated cmd run the following line, I get the error: "740: The requested operation requires elevation." But the CMD I run it in, is elevated som how can I tell runas to elevate it or that it is elevated?

"C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /noprofile /user:aloc-ad\teksupadmin "%windir%\System32\mmc.exe %windir%\System32\virtmgmt.msc""

I have also tried PowerShell:
Start-Process -FilePath c:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe -ArgumentList c:\Windows\System32\virtmgmt.msc -Credential aloc-ad\teksupadmin

But with same result.

Answer (score 0):

Runas will check if the user you hand over to it has elevated rights.
If the user (here teksupadmin) doesn't have elevated rights (or permissions in general) , the program wont run even when you started the cmd with elevated rights.

Comment: The user teksupadmin is domain admin, so I would think that should be enough?

Comment: runas.exe does not check elevation at all AFAIK?